# Holomorphic differential of elliptic curve over $\mathbb C$

Tags: elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, differential

There are well known holomorphic differential of elliptic curve over $\mathbb C$.

That is, $ω＝dx/y＝dx/\sqrt{x(x-1)(x-λ)}$ on $E(\mathbb C)$

But this seems to have pole at $x＝0,1,λ,∞$.

Why these points are not pole?

Comment: You have to use a local parameter to calculate what’s going on at each point. At each of those points, $dx$ has a pole, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $x$ (or $x-1$ or $x-\lambda$) isn’t a local coordinate at these points. The correct coordinate is $y$. Near e.g. $x=0$, $x=y^2\times  f(x)$ with $f(x)$ defined and nonzero, so that $dx/y=2f(x)dy+yf’(x)dx$ is holomorphic. The same works for $x=1,x=\lambda$.

At infinity, it’s a little bit different. Write $z=1/x, v=x/y$, which are regular at infinity (and $v$ is the coordinate) and $x=v^{-2}f(z)$, $y=v^{-3}g(z)$ with $f,g$ defined and nonzero near zero. Then for $x$ near infinity $dx/y=f’(z)dz/(v(g(z))-2f(z)dv/g(z)$. So it’s enough to show $dz/v$ holomorphic at $z=0$. But $z=v^2h(z)$ with $h$ defined and nonzero near $0$ so it concludes.

Comment: How can I prove $x$ is not a local coordinate , for example, at $x＝0$?

Comment: Because $y$ vanishes too and $y^2=xf(x)$ with $f(0)$ invertible. So the maximal ideal of the ring of stalks at $x=y=0$ cannot be generated by $x$.

Comment: dx/y is not holomorphic on PC1(Riemann sphere), right? Then, x＝0,1,λ,∞ is pole on CP1, but not pole on E(C), right?

Comment: We’re working in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ here, so I don’t understand your comment…

Comment: Why $x=y^2\phi(x)$ near $x=0$? And where do $z=1/x,v=x/y$ from?(how did you come up with?) Why is $z$ regular at $\infty=(0:1:0)$?(it seems that "$z=1/0$") Please explain in detail (repetitious explanation is very welcome since I'm beginner).